# Not able to play youtube videos - Failed to load "libpepflashplayer.so"

Tags: 14.04, video, flash, youtube

I am getting the following errors when I play a YouTube video:

```
Failed to load "libpepflashplayer.so"
Freswrapper is a translation layer which needs PPAPI plugin backend. Ensure your system have "libpepflashplayer.so" available.
Paths tried:
/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/opt/google/chrome-beta/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/opt/google/chrome-unstable/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib64/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/chromium/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib64/chromium/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/opt/chromium/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/libpepflashplayer.so
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-bit.

How do I correct the above errors?

Comment: As a side note: Google has withdrawn all support for Chrome on 32-bit systems. See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued for more information. It is something to keep in mind when you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu version. Chromium and Firefox continue to be available on i386 systems.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install the Pepper Flash plugin. Do so by running following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

and then

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

[See this post on WebUpd8 for more details.](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/pepper-flash-player-installer-for.html)

Comment: I tried your commands but didn't worked. First command says its already newest version and second didn't print any log.

Comment: @Patrick, do you have a file named `libpepflashplayer.so` in any of the directories listed in the error log in your question ? What browser are you using ?

Comment: I checked in /usr and /opt but didn't found that .so and I am using firefox 45.0 browser

Answer (score -2):

Google changed the key source. Try this, it worked for me.

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551

gpg --export --armor 1397BC53640DB551 | sudo sh -c 'cat >> /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/pubkey-google.txt'

sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```